# Stored Procedures and Returning a Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure I wrote, that when executed in SSMS works fine, but in code it doesn't.  In code it doesn't seem to like that I'm trying to return a variable.  What would be the cause of this?  I've tried adding `output` to the `SELECT @soLineNumber` statement but that doesn't work.

**The errors I get:**  When moused over the recordset during debug - "The item cannot be found in the collection corresponding ..." and when I 'watch' the variable, it simply says it's closed.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rt_sp_aof_loStart]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @soLineNumber varchar(50)

SELECT
    TOP 1 @soLineNumber = lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]
FROM
    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ
    LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ 
        ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER]
WHERE
    lQ.[SELECTED] = 'False' AND
    lQ.[COMPLETED] = 'False'
ORDER BY
    lQ.[SELECTED] DESC,
    lQ.[COMPLETED] ASC

--

UPDATE
    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE]
SET
    [SELECTED] = 'True'
WHERE
    [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = @soLineNumber

--

SELECT @soLineNumber

END
```

Running a simple test routine yields the same results as well.

```
Private Sub Button2_Released()

    errorPosition = "ThisDisplay.Button1 Test"
    On Error GoTo errorTrap
    Err.Clear

Button2.Enabled = True
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=i.p.add.ress;initial catalog=CATALOG;user id=user;password=pass"
    conn.Open constr
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "rt_sp_aof_loStart"
        .CommandTimeout = 2
    End With
    Set rst(1) = cmd.Execute()

    Do While Not rst(1).EOF
        MsgBox (rst(1)(0))
        rst(1).MoveNext
    Loop


    GoTo cleanExit

cleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 8
        If Not rst(i) Is Nothing Then
            rst(i).Close
        End If
    Next
    conn.Close

    Exit Sub

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "_Eventwatcher2.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.Number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume cleanExit

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Also, why does your sproc have the database and schema names hardcoded? If you ever rename your database, or deploy it to another server (with a different database name) it will break.

Comment: If you're returning a single value from a stored-procedure, consider using an output parameter instead of a `SELECT`.

Comment: vba here is abiguous - what object model are you using? If its access using a pass through query is pretty good approach

Comment: @DougCoats This is a proprietary VBA so I won't get crazy and post the entire procedure, but this is very standard and I havn't had this trouble before.  `DIM recordSet as ADODB.RecordSet                 cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                cmd.CommandText = "rt_sp_aof_loStart" set RecordSet = cmd.execute`.

Comment: @Dai I have tried using an output parameter already as I said in the OP.  I just tried it again for good measure and it yields the same results.

Comment: @Jaberwocky IDK WTF you just said but you have to be using some object model if its VBA. Access, excel, PP, word etc etc. Unless you have literally developed your own VBA object model (doubtful) then you would be using it within an application, hence the A part of VBA.

Comment: @DougCoats if you insist, no need to be crass about it.  It's Rockwell Automation's object model.  FactoryTalk View Studio SE.

Comment: Have you tried adding `set nocount on` as the first statement in your stored procedure.

Comment: can you post the declaration of your recordset array and any initialization of it

Comment: @chrisuae Yes, I did.

Comment: @Phil Will do sir.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `OUTPUT` parameters as a solution to this problem.

Moved declaration above `AS` statement to parameterize.  Added `OUTPUT`.  Removed `SELECT @soLineNumber` from bottom of SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rt_sp_aof_loStart]
@soLineNumber varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT
    TOP 1 @soLineNumber = lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]
FROM
    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ
    LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ 
        ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER]
WHERE
    lQ.[SELECTED] = 'False' AND
    lQ.[COMPLETED] = 'False'
ORDER BY
    lQ.[SELECTED] DESC,
    lQ.[COMPLETED] ASC

--

UPDATE
    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE]
SET
    [SELECTED] = 'True'
WHERE
    [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = @soLineNumber

--

END
```

And my VB test code outputs the parameter as a msgbox.  This works with multiple parameters when you specify multiple in both the SP and VBA.  Added `.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@soLineNumber", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 50)` and refer to `cmd.Parameters("@soLineNumber").Value` after cmd.execute.

```
Private Sub Button2_Released()

    errorPosition = "ThisDisplay.Button1 Test"
    On Error GoTo errorTrap
    Err.Clear

    Button2.Enabled = True
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=i.p.add.ress;initial catalog=catalog;user id=user;password=pass"
    conn.Open constr

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "rt_sp_aof_loStart"
        .CommandTimeout = 2
        .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@soLineNumber", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 50)
        .Execute
    End With

    MsgBox cmd.Parameters("@soLineNumber").Value

    GoTo cleanExit

cleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    conn.Close

    Exit Sub

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "_Eventwatcher2.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.Number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume cleanExit

End Sub
```